# Can't shutdown Linux guest OS with `at` command

Tags: virtual-machine, shutdown, at

Here are three examples of what I did inside the terminal
(the third one has sudo):

1. ```
   at now + 5 minutes
   ```

   (interactively:)

   ```
   at> shutdown --poweroff now
   ```
2. ```
   echo "sbin/shutdown -h now" | at 14:50
   ```
3. ```
   echo "/sbin/shutdown -h 16:22" | at now
   ```

In every case,
I can verify the one-time job is scheduled with the `atq` command,
but the `shutdown --show` command says "No scheduled shutdown".

The system should shutdown at the scheduled time that `at` runs
after sleeping.

This is on a CentOS 9 Stream guest virtual machine. 
The user is already added to the sudo users group
and can initiate the shutdown with a command like `shutdown now`. 
So, with the one-time `at` job, what’s the difference?

Comment: (1) You say you did `echo "sbin/shutdown -h now"`.  Try `echo "/sbin/shutdown -h now"` (if that isn’t what you actually did).  (2) Do other commands scheduled with `at` run?  For example, try running `cp /dev/null /tmp/foo` with `at`.  (3) What kind of virtual machine is it?  I.e., what hypervisor are you using?    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*The user is already added to the sudo users group*" - but you don't use `sudo` anywhere. You need to apply the administrative privileges somewhere by using the `sudo` command. For example:

```
# Use root's "at"
echo /sbin/shutdown -h now | sudo at now +5 minutes
```

or

```
# Use your "at" with an embedded "sudo shutdown…"
echo sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now | at now +5 minutes
```

However, rather than running `at` it seems that it would seem to make more sense to fire the `shutdown` command with a specific time and avoid `at` entirely:

```
sudo shutdown -h "$(date --date '+5 min' +'%H:%M')"
```

Comment: Specifically echo "/sbin/shutdown -h now" | sudo at now + TimeInterval worked succesfully but embedding the sudo into the shutdown command did not work for me. Maybe something funky with the system but it seems like creating the job itself permissionwise was the issue and not the piped through command. It could be something weird like a bug. but anywho making sudo work with at was frustrating although ChrisD is right using a scheduled shutdown command would be what you should do generally. Thanks man!